# How to use one function variable to another function in abstract class

Tags: php, abstract-class

```
abstract class Dropboxapi {
    protected $webAuth;

    protected function abi() {
        require __DIR__.'/app/Dropbox/autoload.php';
        self::start();
        self::dropbox_auth();
    }

    public function start() {
        $webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'path',$csrfTokenStore);
    }

    public function dropbox_auth() {
        $authUrl = $webAuth->start();
    }
}
    Dropboxapi::abi();
```

Here i have `$webAuth` object in start function. When I use this in `dropbox_auth` it shows `Undefined variable: webAuth`.

When i use `$this->webAuth` i'm getting `Using $this when not in object context`

i tried like self::webAuth also. This is showing  `Access to undeclared static property:`. So I don't understand how to use that.

Comment: Why you need abstract class here, remove abstract and use $this context

Comment: no i need to use abstract class.that is the requirement

Comment: Try making your webAuth property a static variable

Comment: ya i tried like protected static $webAuth also.but the dropbox_auth function variable $webAuth is undefined

Comment: Read about [PHP Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: I think in this case you no need to use abstract class..@Phoenix bang

Comment: can you help me for simple class @lalithkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the abstract method is defined as protected, the function implementation must be defined as either protected or public, but not private.

Many example are [there](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) for abstract class.Just check how you can or not.As you asked without abstract just define the class and function like below.Here all the variable and methods are $this context.

```
class Dropboxapi {
    public $this->webAuth='';
    public function abi() {
        require __DIR__.'/app/Dropbox/autoload.php';
        $this->webAuth = new 
        Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'path',$csrfTokenStore);
    }
    public function dropbox_auth() {
        $authUrl = $this->webAuth->start();
    }
}
    $dropbox = new Dropboxapi();
    $dropbox->dropbox_auth();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining things wrong. Abstract class, similar with interface, are tend to be used as "blueprint" class. It means they need to be extended by another classes to be used, and cannot be used by itself as is. Using `$this` in abstract class is fine, as in documentation of abstract by php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php.

What you need to do, is to have another class that inherit / extends that `DropBoxApi` class of yours, ex:

```
class DropBoxApi2 extends DropBoxApi
{

}
```

As class `DropBoxApi2` is inherited, then it already has functions and property of it's parent (`DropBoxApi`). And you can use it like (example):

```
$api = new DropBoxApi2();
$api->start();
```

Additionally, the double colon that you use is static operator. Which is far far different concept than abstract.

Answer (score -1):

Sample Code. Replace with your requirement.

you have to make everything as static

```
abstract class Dropboxapi {
    protected static $webAuth;

    public static function abi() {
       self::start();
       self::dropbox_auth();
    }

    public static function start() {
        self::$webAuth = new Stdclass();
    }

    public static function dropbox_auth() {
       var_dump(self::$webAuth);
    }
}

Dropboxapi::abi();
```

Comment: yes .when i declared all the function as static then it works.

Comment: Thank you @Subash

Comment: Where is the OOP in this code? I cannot find it. All I can see are some global variables and functions inside some fancy namespace called `Dropboxapi`.

Comment: It's a lot of wrapping that mimics OOP when, in essence, it is procedural programming. Drop the class wrap, drop `public static`, drop `self::` and `Dropboxapi::` and you get the exact same procedural code with shorter names. Nothing is wrong writing procedural code but I think it's terribly wrong to write procedural code disguised as OOP.

Comment: i could not understand.i am newbie @axiac

Comment: @axiac in his question he mentioned that it is not working. how make it work showing that code

Comment: please suggest the best way to write that code @axiac